# Does SQL Server acquire locks even without an explicit transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, transactions, locking

I was reading about MSSQL Locking for the first time, and it many places, the locking mechanism concepts depend on the existence of Transactions. I was wondering whether locking (in general) is possible without having any Transactions involved?

Comment: *Every* database, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Access, SQLite executes the basic commands inside an implicit transaction. Depending on your isolation mode that may or may not mean locks

Comment: Transactions will keep locks after the DML statement has finished and until there is a commit or rollback, but locks can exist while the DML statement is running even if there is no transaction.

Comment: @cloudsafe "even if there is no transaction" you mean no explicit transaction right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When no explicit transaction exists, each SQL statement is executed in an automatic (autocommit) transaction. Normal locking behavior will apply in that case and the locks released when the automatic transaction is completed as the statement completes.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Under several isolation levels, including the default READ COMMITTED, queries take shared (S) locks, which will block the locks required to change data.

Every UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and MERGE runs in a single-statement transaction, even if you don't explicitly start a transaction via `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.

Comment: worth mentioning that this is not MSSQL specific, relational databases that support ACID properties do these things